# CSV StreamReader deletes blanks (semicolon)

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader

When I read a CSV (smicolon separated) with this method:

```
public List<string> LoadCSV()
{
    List<string> displayName = new List<string>();
    List<string> groupName = new List<string>();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"\\aPath\to\aFile.csv"))
    {

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            String line = reader.ReadLine();
            String[] values = line.Split(';');

            displayName.Add(values[0]);
            groupName.Add(values[6]);
        }
    }
    return displayName;
}
```

The blanks in displayName get deleted.
One line in the file:

> Adobe Acrobat Standard - (Win XP);16477;2;3657;AD Group;1233xxoo_AcrobatStd;1835

For my understanding, this should give for the line above this result:

```
Adobe Acrobat Standard - (Win XP)
```

But it's this:

`AdobeAcrobatStandard-(WinXP)`

Can somebody help?

It's an OutlookAddin. This is how I run the method:

```
    string bodyText = "RealNames:\n"; 
foreach (string s in LoadCSV()) { 
               bodyText += s +"\n"; 
            } 
openMail.Body = bodyText;
```

Comment: Why did you write your own CSV parser? Why not use a library, which already handles many of the complexes nuances of a CSV file?

Comment: Why do you have a list for display names and a separate one for groups? Shouldn't you define a type so that you can maintain the relationship of which display name goes with which group name?

Comment: I only needed the first column (and later the 7th), so it seemed that this was the quickest solution. Now it appears to be not so fast. :)
But anyway it's a little bit of a mystery why the blanks are missing.

Comment: comment to the second question: for now I only need the first "column" and later the 7th.

Comment: That still doesn't address my point: you are losing the relationship between the display name and the group name, by storing them in separate lists. You should create a type to represent the data and maintain a single list.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I will do this after I solved the blank problem.

Comment: There is no way that the code above could remove the blanks between the words in the first field. Should be something else.

Comment: Any idea where I should search? Maybe a stupid question, but is there a way it could be an outlook setting?

Comment: Use the debugger to check what's coming out from your file. Or an HEX editor to be sure that the white space between your words is really the ASCII code for the space (int 32, 0x20)

Comment: That's the solution. The blank was indeed not a 'real blank'. Thank you!